# SVN Ignore - how to ignore the content of a directory

Tags: svn

I have a large project on a live server which I would like to commit to an svn repo. I have added all files and directories to the repository using `svn add`.

The problem is that there is a folder-structure that I want to commit but without its content. The folder name is:

> ```
> /home/myproject/media/
> ```

It contains various folders such as images, adverts news, home-images, etc. I would like to commit these folders but not their content. I have tried doing the following:

> ```
> cd /home/myproject/media/
> svn propedit svn:ignore ./homeimages/
> {{The text editor comes up}}
> I entered * and saved
> ```

but when I do

> svn stat

the files under `homeimages` are still listed in the repository. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Once added to subversion, the svn:ignore property no longer applies.  You will first have to do an `svn remove` on the contents of your media folder.  Once that is done, SVN should ignore the files as you requested.

Comment: ok i have done an svn revert on the media folder. But when i try to set the svn ignore propety it says that the directory is not a working copy :S

Comment: Try doing an `svn add -N /home/myproject/media`.  The -N parameter tells subversion to not recurse down the tree.  That should add just the media directory itself, and none of its content.  You can then add the svn:ignore property.

Comment: If you don't want to add the media directory at all, then `svn propset svn:ignore /home/myproject` and specify `media` in your editor.

Comment: if you already have it versioned then just ignore * on the folder: `svn propset svn:ignore '*' /home/myproject/media`

Answer (score 1):

I use SVN client (Tortoise SVN) and it has ignore-on-commit functionality. Try use that.

Comment: Tortise SVN is a Windows SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert adding *files* and leave only *folders* added.

```
svn revert --depth files
```

You will have to do it in every subfolder of `/home/myproject/media/`.